# Ant replace token - Gradle

Tags: gradle, ant

I am trying to understand a multi-build spring boot project. In one of the sub project it has a build.gradle file, and the first line is:

> import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

From what I read on Google, I understand this is to replace some ant property files, however I'm unable to find any more information. Can someone please help me understand how this works and what it does?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line by itself doesn't do anything. It is just telling gradle/java to import the class ReplaceTokens for later use in the build script. If you look through the file, you'll likely find where they're actually using it.

If you can post more of the build.gradle file, I/someone will be able to help more.

And you're right, this class is used to do find and replaces in other files.